# Jquery get elements

Tags: jquery, each, html-lists

HI I have following problem, i have a ul list like this one

```
<ul class="ul">
    <li id="li1">
        <span class="widget">
            <input name='try1' value="try1" class="param" />
        </span>
        <ul>
            <li class="li2">
                <span class="widget">
                    <input name='try1' value="try1" class="param" />
                    <input name='try2' value="try2" class="param" />
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<li id="2"></li>
</ul>
```

my problem is when i try to get inputs in this way

```
$('#li1 .param').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('name'));
    });
```

each returns to me 
try1
try1
try2
But i need only these ones between span if someone knows how to get them?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: be more specific, all of the inputs in that code ARE inside a span tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to understand, but I assume you mean that you only want the ones that descend from the child `<span>` element instead of all `<span>` elements.

If so, do this:

```
$('#li1 > span .param').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

This uses the the [`child-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to target `.param` elements that descend from a `<span>` element that is a child of `#li1`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't want the `.param`s inside the nested `<ul>`.

You can write `$('#li1>.widget .param')` to get all `.param`s in `.widget`s *directly* inside `#li1`.